# Is there a way to create multiple points in one layer of a Cartodb map and edit them each separately?

Tags: carto, html-popup

I am making a Cartodb map that is supposed to show different pictures of a park in popups at points along a park path.  I started by making a different layer for each point but by the time I created 4 layers it looked like it was going to stop allowing me to create any more.  I have around 30 unique popups that I need to make.  Is there a way to create multiple points in one layer and edit them each separately?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your account type, CARTO has a limit of layers that you can add per map. For example FREE accounts have 4 layers as a limit.

It is possible to edit the points of the layer and edit each point (each point/geometry is stored in the_geom column of the dataset) in the data view of the map or of the dataset that you are using to create the map.

If I understood you correctly (let me know if I'm wrong!) you want to add a different picture for each popup. You could add a column where each row of the column could contain a different URL (1 row = 1 geometry and its attributes) of each image on your dataset and then use the infowindow "image header" template to display the images in the popups.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'm still having trouble.  I added a column & 3 rows in the data view and added 3 points within one layer to see if they would correspond to the rows.  I added a different URL & a description into each row of the new column.  Then checked to see if that would show up in the popups.  My html in the infowindow is still all that comes up in the popups, the same picture and description shows in each popup.  I tried deleting my html but that just left me with an empty popup.  Can you explain how to get the URL & description in the rows of the data view to show up in my popups?

Comment: i would recommend writting to CARTO support( support@carto.com ) explaining your usecase.